# Blender Hand Twisting

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

[image]

If I twist the hand, the wrist also twists (as shown in photo).

Blend File :
[image]

Comment: Have you done weight painting?

Comment: No, but I don't know how to or where to paint

Comment: Okay , so you are not that experienced.... not a problemo , Select the mesh in the outliner , then switch to weight paint mode , then Shift rightclick on the bone which you want to affect the wrist , and then paint , you can go and watch some tutorials

Comment: Thanks I'll Try that now.

Comment: Its not working

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: i put the blend file in

Comment: I've searched all over the internet i cant find the fix.

Comment: In real life you cant twist your wrist only your forearm. So this is not a weight problem. You have to add two bones in the forearm and twist one of them, as you can see it MakeHuman or Manuel Bastioni Lab.

Comment: Okay but is there a way i can add a bone without having to redo all the fingers

Answer (score 1):

It seems normal that if you rotate the hand, the wrist mesh get twisted too. What you should do is make the forearm rotate as well so that the torsion looks more natural.

To do so you need to give your forearm bone a *Copy Rotation* constraint, with the left hand as *Target* and *Space > Pose Space /Pose Space*. The problem is that for the moment it will mess up because the forearm can’t be both the parent of the hand and be affected by the rotation of the hand.

So what you should do is:

- Create a bone under the wrist, it will be the controller bone, parent it to the armature root bone (in *Keep Offset* mode).
- Parent the hand to the controller (in *Keep Offset* mode).
- Give the forearm a second constraint, the *Inverse Kinematic* constraint, with the controller as target, and a *Chain Length* of 2 (it controls the fore arm and the upper arm).

Now when you rotate the controller, it makes the hand rotate, and it makes the forearm move and rotate as well.

Also maybe in *Edit* mode, pull the elbow a bit downards so that the arm bend a bit, and create a bone (parented to the root as well) that you put behind the elbow to create the *Inverse Kinematic Pole Target*.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by the left hand as target and space?

Comment: And What Is A Controller

Comment: these are the settings of the Copy Rotation constraint

Comment: And How Do I Add Inverse Kinematics

Comment: the controller will be the bone you'll create, and Inverse Kinematic is a constraint, maybe follow some tutorials about rigging if it's not clear enough

Comment: so how do i make a controller?

Comment: create a normal bone, I call it a controller because it will control the hand and the forearm because you're going to parent the hand to this bone and you're going to choose this bone as the Target of the forearm Inverse Kinematic constraint

Comment: I'm using inverse kinematics in my Unity game for this model already

Comment: I didn't see any IK in the linked file

Comment: Not With The File, In Unity.

Comment: But doesnt it seem that when normal humans rotate the hand , the wrist also moves?

Comment: @ SHikha Mittal, what seems normals is that when you rotate the hand, the wrist and the forearm rotate as well